# Consume API from inside Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a **Cloud Function** to run an API for OpenWeather. This is so I can have my API key secure on the server side.

How can I do that? I'm going to be using *callable function* on my front-end to call the function I want but I don't know how I can connect the OpenWeather API on the cloud function. Make sense?

I'm using TS.

Thanks

Comment: OpenWeather seems to have an NPM module, which is probably a good place to get started: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openweather-apis

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. I meant like how to connect to the url. I figured out using `fetch()`. Thank you!